# add space to alfresco which is only visible by admin

Tags: java, alfresco

I want to add a space in the home of the administrator on alfresco but I want the space to be visible only to the administrator (adminstrator home is the Company Home).
I used this code to add the space in the admin's home but the hidden part I don't know how to use:

```
NodeRef personNodeRef = personService.getPerson("admin");
NodeRef homespaceNodeRef = (NodeRef) nodeService.getProperty(
        personNodeRef, 
        ContentModel.PROP_HOMEFOLDER);
serviceRegistry.getFileFolderService().create(
        homespaceNodeRef, 
        LOG_FOLDER_NAME,
        ContentModel.TYPE_FOLDER);
```

I'm persuaded that I'm gonna add a property but I don't know which, can any one help ?

Comment: you want to do it from code only? othewise from user interface you can simply create space and uncheck inherit space permission then only admin will be able to see that space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it via code and looking for api

PermissionService of alfresco has API

```
void setInheritParentPermissions(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef nodeRef, boolean inheritParentPermissions)
```

if you pass true in second argument it will set inheripermission as false so none of the other person able to see space create by admin(provided space is created by admin user)

otherwise as I had suggested in comment you can do it from user interface as well.